# Basic Game Using HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and have to make a "madlib" game for class. It just needs to be basic. I need the user to fill in 4 words and replace those words for any random ones I choose in a poem or short story. The problem I'm having it that I need the poem/short story to be in the body of web page after it has been "madlibbed".

I'm really not sure how I can take some JavaScript from the head and insert it into the body. Here's what I have so far and I'll try to be specific in what my thoughts/confusions are. Don't worry if there are specific little errors in the code so far, I can figure that out later.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mad Lib</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{ var noun=prompt(“Type a noun here”);
var noun2=prompt(“Type a noun here”);
var verb=prompt(“Type a verb here”);
var verb2=prompt(“Type a verb here”);}</script>
</head><body>
<p>sad indeed, there are other (noun) still freedom from (noun2) no ideas
, from this dryness, freedom from having (verb) as a poet on forced (verb 2)</p>
</body></html>
```

So basically I'm trying to declare variables in the script and have users enter their answers as a prompt. I'm then trying to take their answers and insert them into the body of the paragraph where I've put (noun) (noun2) (verb) and (verb2). I'm sorry this is so elementary and I can't figure this out. I don't expect you to write the whole code out for me, you can just give me conceptual advice.

Also if you're having problems non-coding related that I might be able to help with I could try to help you with that :D

Comment: Do not copy/paste from websites or from other documents. Type out the code yourself. I can tell by the curly quotes in `“Type a noun here”`. The curly quotes are a syntax error. The valid quote mark is `"`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I copy/pasted some lines but didn't realize it was bad. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Please use this [tool](https://infohound.net/tidy/) to correct your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the text in a variable and use the string replace function to get your content in:

```
    var input = prompt("word");
    var text = "My text PLACEHOLDER1";
    var newText = text.replace("PLACEHOLDER1", input);
    // render text to dom
    document.getElementById('myId').innerText = newText;
```

More advanced would be usage of a regular expression or a template engine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I appreciate it. I don't recognize some of the tags from class so I will try to use the one below before this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like giving direct answers when it's obviously for class, so I'll try to point you to a few helpful starting places.

First, you are going to want the user to be able to enter the required verbs, nouns, etc. So, setup a form that has several [text inputs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).

Next, I would put a button that does a couple things when clicked. First, it would check to make sure none of the text boxes are empty (we want the person to participate, after all). Then, the button will get the input from the user and insert it into the quote where needed. Finally, it will output the whole quote. To do this, I would create a [function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) that, when the user clicks, would write to the [p tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) something like this:

```
"sad indeed, there are other " + noun1 + " still freedom from " + noun2 +  
"no ideas, from this dryness, freedom from having "...etc.
```

My final hint: You can update the value of the p tag (I say 'p' because that is what you mentioned earlier. Personally, I would make it a div) if you give it an ID and reference that ID like this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp (under more examples, you'll see how to set that to the variables noun1 and noun2).

Leave a comment if you need more hints.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I replied much later than i'd hoped for because of other classes and weather. I do have a couple questions though. I'm on a train so I can only use my phone(can't code) but hopefully you can help me understand. I get the concept of putting in quotes and adding the value tags of nouns and verbs to complete the paragraphs. The problem I have is that in the body I don't know how to add in anything that wouldn't directly show up.For example I wouldn't know how to say "sad indeed there are other" +noun1...(end example) without the page having quotes or a + sign.